# onclick on button,i want the button to be coloured as well as store a value

Tags: javascript, java, html, css

here,i have 3 fields-temp,hum,number.In Temp field,i have created four buttons.The functionality i want is that,when i click on 1st button then 1st button should be coloured  and store a value='1'.

And similarly when i clicked on 2nd button then i want 1st,2nd buttons should coloured and store a value='2'.

when i clicked on 3rd button then i want 1st,2nd,3rd buttons should coloured and store a value='3'.

when i clicked on 4th button then i want all buttons should coloured and store a value='4'.
 Same i want  for hum n number field.how can i do???.Any help will be useful!!!!!

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div align='left'>Temp</div>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';" value="2">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';" value="3">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';" value="4">
<br><br>

<div align='left'>Hum</div>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';" value="2">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';" value="3">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';" value="4">
<br><br>

<div align='left'>number</div>
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';" value="1">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';" value="2">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';" value="3">
<input type="button" class="button" onclick="this.style.backgroundColor = 'orange';" value="4">
<br><br>
<input type='submit' value='submit'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to change each button background color

```js
$("#Temp1").click(function() {
  $("#Temp4").css("background-color", "");
  $("#Temp3").css("background-color", "");
  $("#Temp2").css("background-color", "");
  $("#Temp1").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#temp").text(1);
});

$("#Temp2").click(function() {
  $("#Temp4").css("background-color", "");
  $("#Temp3").css("background-color", "");
  $("#Temp2").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("#Temp1").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#temp").text(2);
});

$("#Temp3").click(function() {
  $("#Temp4").css("background-color", "");
  $("#Temp3").css("background-color", "green");
  $("#Temp2").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("#Temp1").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#temp").text(3);
});

$("#Temp4").click(function() {
  $("#Temp4").css("background-color", "orange");
  $("#Temp3").css("background-color", "green");
  $("#Temp2").css("background-color", "yellow");
  $("#Temp1").css("background-color", "red");
  $("#temp").text(4);
});
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div align='left'>Temp: <span id="temp"></span></div>
<input type="button" class="button" id="Temp1">
<input type="button" class="button" id="Temp2">
<input type="button" class="button" id="Temp3">
<input type="button" class="button" id="Temp4">
<br><br>

<input type='submit' value='submit'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done to only temp part, you can do it other as same

I have done some changes in html, I have put id for input tags and removed onClick() function and added in jQuery file.

```
<div align='left'>Temp</div>
<input type="button" class="button"  value="1" id="one">
<input type="button" class="button"  value="2" id="two">
<input type="button" class="button"  value="3" id="three">
<input type="button" class="button"  value="4" id="four">
<br><br>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#one").click(function(){
$('#one').css('background-color','red');
alert('one');
$("#one").val()=1;
$("#one").attr('value', '1');
})
$("#two").click(function(){
$('#two').css('background-color','yellow');
$('#one').css('background-color','red');
$("#one").attr('value', '2');
$("#two").attr('value', '2');
})

$("#three").click(function(){
$('#two').css('background-color','yellow');
$('#one').css('background-color','red');
$('#three').css('background-color','green');
$("#one").attr('value', '3');
$("#two").attr('value', '3');
$("#three").attr('value', '3');
})

$("#four").click(function(){
$('#two').css('background-color','yellow');
$('#one').css('background-color','red');
$('#three').css('background-color','green');
$('#four').css('background-color','grey');
$("#one").attr('value', '4');
$("#two").attr('value', '4');
$("#three").attr('value', '4');
$("#four").attr('value', '4');
})
});
```